# AutoLayout conflict errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm getting some conflict errors for my AutoLayout setup in the console.

I know what they mean.

How can I find which views the errors are referring to?

I know I saw a WWDC video where the guy set some identifiers on the views so that the AutoLayout errors were more readable.

At the moment I have...

```
( 
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x20964090 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x1fdddbf0(480)]>", 
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1fde8000 H:[UIView:0x1fdb35a0(320)]>", 
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1fdb3dc0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1fdb35a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1fdb7040 )>", 
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1fdb3d80 UIView:0x1fdb35a0.trailing == UIView:0x1fdb7040.trailing>", 
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1fd66e30 h=-&& v=-&& UIView:0x1fdb7040.width == UIView:0x1fdddbf0.width>" 
)
```

I know it's probably the AutoresizingMask causing the error I'm just not sure WHICH AutoresizingMask.

Comment: So do you want to know which constraint is causing the error or how you can make identifying which constraint does what easier?

Comment: I'd like to be able to have the log show "PlayPauseView" instead of "UIView" or whichever actual view this is. There is a WWDC video where the guy does this but I can't find the controls he used to enable it. He set the "Identifier" of each element. i.e. "UILabel" becomes "Title Label" in the AutoLayout error log.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I've only had it show the labels when I add the constraints in code and give them assigned names.  If you're adding them through the storyboard you can try adding XCode Identifiers to your view, but when I've hit that problem I usually add some NSLog statements to print out the views I'm interested in, eg

```
NSLog(@"My View: %@", self.myView);
```

That will show me the id for the view, hopefully something like

```
My View: UIView:0x1fdddbf0
```

in your case.

That said, I'm not sure that even knowing what the views are will help you much here.  The standard advice is to turn Autoresizing Mask off for views that use autolayout.  I don't have much experience reconciling those, but it looks like the problem is that one view is set to be 320pt wide and the autoresizing mask has added constraints that will set it to be 480pt wide.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone else who finds this: you can do this in Interface Builder using the instructions in [this post](http://www.archaeopterasa.net/2014/11/15/more-readable/). Basically you override the internal method that generates those "UIView:0xwhatever" substrings with this code:

```
@implementation UIView (AutoLayoutDebugging)
- (void)setLayoutDebuggingIdentifier:(NSString *)readableName {
#ifdef DEBUG
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"layoutDebuggingIdentifier",
                             readableName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
#endif
}
#ifdef DEBUG
- (NSString *)_layoutDebuggingIdentifier {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"layoutDebuggingIdentifier");
}
#endif
@end
```

Then you can select any view in IB and set the user-defined runtime attribute "layoutDebuggingIdentifier" to whatever string you want to see in the AutoLayout error.